# SQL Loop dynamic select "equals" in stored procedure

Tags: sql, loops, stored-procedures

I am trying to do the following and do not understand why it will not work.  I do not understand.

```
DECLARE @month_1 NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @month_2 NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @month_3 NVARCHAR(50)

DECLARE @intFlag NVARCHAR(50)

SET @intFlag = 1
WHILE (@intFlag <=3)
BEGIN
SELECT  '@month' +'_'+ @intFlag = datepart(month, getdate())

print '@month' +'_'+ @intFlag 
SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
END
GO
```

Comment: You are trying to assign the value dynamically to different variables. This requires dynamic SQL.
Also @intFlag is integer, this needs to be converted to varchar, also you are assinging same month to all variables. what is intent?

Comment: I was attempting to have select @month_1= datepart(month, getdate()), @month_2= datepart(month, getdate()) (etc) assigned by the @intFlag looping in a stored procedure.

Comment: but it is same month, any how you need dynamic sql. is this just experimentation

Comment: Yes it will be the same month for each one (@month_1, @month_2 etc) I need the variable names to be dynamic I then use a PLC transaction manager to read the "@variables"..I am trying to understand how to get past "@month+'_'+@intFlag = datepart(month, getdate()) without the error (Incorrect syntax near '=').